# Why do we want the Periodic Points to be dense for a Chaotic Map?

Tags: real-analysis, chaos-theory

Devaney defines a dynamical system on $S$ with an iterator function $f:S\rightarrow S$ as being chaotic if we have

- sensitivity to initial conditions;
- topological mixing; and
- the set of period points being dense.

I can understand *why* we might want sensitivity to initial conditions (butterfly effect) and *why* we might want it to topologically mixing (there are orbits that don't seem to have any 'pattern').

> Why however might we want our chaotic dynamical system to have the set
>   of periodic points dense in $S$?

I familiar with the relationships between the conditions in different categories.

Comment: Denseness of the periodic points implies an underlying structure. If, in addition, there's a dense orbit (topological mixing) we can say that every open set of the space contains points with very different behavior.

Comment: So not only is regular (periodic) behavior possible it is very close to very 'random looking' behavior... so that not only do we have sensitivity to initial conditions in the sense of diverging iterates but also sensitivity to initial conditions that two 'close' seeds can have very different behaviour? Am I interpreting your comment correctly?

Comment: I think your interpretation of my comment is correct, at least in part. It's definitely multifaceted, though. A major "discovery" of chaos is that seemingly random phenomena can have a relatively simple origin and have hidden patterns. In this case, the "hidden patterns" are the periodic orbits. They tend to be mostly repulsive so they're hard to find and, in that sense, hidden.

Comment: @MarkMcClure would you like to turn your comments into an answer that I would accept?

Comment: @MarkMcClure Well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denseness of the periodic points implies an underlying structure. If, in addition, there's a dense orbit (topological mixing) we can say that every open set of the space contains points with very different behavior.

So not only is regular (periodic) behavior possible, it is very close to very 'random looking' behavior... so that not only do we have sensitivity to initial conditions in the sense of diverging iterates but also sensitivity to initial conditions that two 'close' seeds can have very different behaviour.

A major "discovery" of chaos is that seemingly random phenomena can have a relatively simple origin and have hidden patterns. In this case, the "hidden patterns" are the periodic orbits. They tend to be mostly repulsive so they're hard to find and, in that sense, hidden.